# Connection between controller and view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, connection

In **users_controller.rb** I've got my method:

```
def showallusers
 @users = User.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html  # showallusers.html.erb
  format.json  { render :json => @users }
 end
end
```

and in **app/views/users** I've got **showallusers.html.erb** and in it:

```
<p>test</p>
```

but when I type

```
 http://localhost:3000/users/showallusers
```

in browser, it shows me **show.html.erb** instead.

My **routes.rb**

```
  resources :users

  resources :projects do
    resources :issues  
  end

  #resources :issues

  resources :projects

  resources :sessions


  root :to => "users#index"

  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
```

Do you know, what is wrong and how can I fix it? thanks

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: I would recommend that you do some reading up on Rails routing and on resources in particular. Showing all users is something you would typically use the index-action to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :showallusers # why not :show_all_users? Isn't it more readable?
    # you may also need
    # post :showallusers
  end
end
```

Then restart your server to make sure the new url-helpers are generated (the new helper should be `showallusers_users_path`)

Comment: It is not black magic, you have to declare all new url / paths in your Routes file ;)

Comment: I thought that "resources :users" makes it for all url for user :)

Comment: No it just deploys the "basic" urls for the CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete). which means it generates these 4 urls needed to create, show, edit and delete an Object.